# How to define a graph using a distance matrix in igraph? (R)

Tags: r, igraph

I have a distance matrix from N points that I'd like to use to create a fully connected graph between N nodes.

So far I've tried the `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` function, but if my distance matrix is:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0   10    3
[2,]   10    0    2
[3,]    3    2    0
```

then I create the graph:

```
g3 =  graph_from_adjacency_matrix(dist_matrix, weighted=TRUE, mode="undirected")
```

But when I plot it, node 2 doesn't seem to be further from node 1 than node 3 is.

Is there a way to define the graph from this matrix and then plot it (with nodes closer to each other when the distance is smaller and vice versa)?

Comment: Just include the distance as weights. `E(g3)$weights<- ....`

Comment: Your "distance matrix" does not satisfy  the triangle inequality.   D(1, 3) + D(3,2) < D(1,2)  This cannot be true for Euclidean distances.

Comment: Several of igraph's layout algorithms support weights. Some draw higher weight edges are longer, some as shorter ("stronger" connection). Check the documentation. That said, consider carefully whether you want to use multidimensional scaling instead.